# Call somebody over VS Call over somebody

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

As far as I know, the structures "call somebody over" and "call somebody over somewhere" are correct. How about "call over somebody" and "call over somebody somewhere"? Can we use these too?

For example, are these sentences interchangeable?

- **"I called over John."**

and

- **"I called John over."**

And how about these two:

- **"I called over John to my place."**

and

- **"I called John over to my place."**

Are these interchangeable?

*Note*: You can see the meaning of "call over" [here.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/call+over) On that dictionary, one of the example sentences is "Call over the waitress", and that makes me wonder if we can also use the **call over somebody** structure.

Answer (score 1):

Both "I called over John" and "I called John over" are correct and adding "to my place" is also fine. The only problem with the "call over somebody" structure is that it's less commonly used, except perhaps in speech when one was thinking first or more strongly of the calling than who is being called. I suppose (at least AmE) native English users tend to associate the verb and its direct object more strongly than the direct object and its preposition.

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you for your question. It is an opportunity for all of us here on the site to learn. :)

Answer (score 0):

"I called over John to my place." is much more awkward than "I called John over to my place." When "over" introduces a further prepositional phrase, or when the subject is a pronoun, "over" should be placed after the object. For instance, "I called him over" rather than "I called over him".